# Why is nativescript-drawingpad leaving a semitransparent white background after being cleared on ios?

Tags: javascript, ios, nativescript

I have a problem with running nativescript-drawingpad, which can be found here https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-drawingpad, on my mac. I am developing for ios and every time when the drawing is being cleared it leaves a white semitransparent background. Does anyone know why this is happening? I have been trying to identify the cause of this with no success.

Comment: I believe you should post this as an issue/question/ask for information in the plugin repo.

Comment: I blame pkanev...